# How to run a groupby based on result of other/previous groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's assume you are selling a product globally and you want to set up a sales office somewhere in a major city. Your decision will be based purely on sales numbers.

This will be your (simplified) sales data:

```
df={
'Product':'Chair',
'Country': ['USA','USA', 'China','China','China','China','India', 
'India','India','India','India','India', 'India'],
'Region': ['USA_West','USA_East', 'China_West','China_East','China_South','China_South', 'India_North','India_North', 'India_North','India_West','India_West','India_East','India_South'],
'City': ['A','B', 'C','D','E', 'F', 'G','H','I', 'J','K', 'L', 'M'],
'Sales':[1000,1000, 1200,200,200, 200,500 ,350,350,100,700,50,50]  
}

dff=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)

dff
```

Based on the data you should go for City "G".

The logic should go like this:

1) Find country with Max(sales)

2) in that country, find region with Max(sales)

3) in that region, find city with Max(sales)

I tried: `groupby('Product', 'City').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1))`, but this doesn't work, because it would propose city "C". This is the city with highest sales globally, but China is not the Country with highest sales.

I probably have to go through several loops of groupby. Based on the result, filter the original dataframe and do a groupby again on the next level.

To add to the complexity, you sell other products too (not just 'Chairs', but also other furniture). You would have to store the results of each iteration (like country with Max(sales) per product) somewhere and then use it in the next iteration of the groupby.

Do you have any ideas, how I could implement this in pandas/python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is aggregate `sum` per each level with [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for top1 value, what is used for filtering for next level by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
max_country = dff.groupby('Country')['Sales'].sum().idxmax()
max_region = dff[dff['Country'] == max_country].groupby('Region')['Sales'].sum().idxmax()
max_city = dff[dff['Region'] == max_region].groupby('City')['Sales'].sum().idxmax()
print (max_city)
G
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks, jezrael! I was not aware of the idxmax() method.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add groupwise totals, then sort your dataframe. This goes beyond your requirement by ordering all your data using your preference logic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)

factors = ['Country', 'Region', 'City']
for factor in factors:
    df[f'{factor}_Total'] = df.groupby(factor)['Sales'].transform('sum')

res = df.sort_values([f'{x}_Total' for x in factors], ascending=False)

print(res.head(5))

   City Country Product       Region  Sales  Country_Total  Region_Total  \
6     G   India   Chair  India_North    500           2100          1200   
7     H   India   Chair  India_North    350           2100          1200   
8     I   India   Chair  India_North    350           2100          1200   
10    K   India   Chair   India_West    700           2100           800   
9     J   India   Chair   India_West    100           2100           800   

    City_Total  
6          500  
7          350  
8          350  
10         700  
9          100
```

So for the most desirable you can use `res.iloc[0]`, for the second `res.iloc[1]`, etc.